# how can i combine 2 tables and including if clause into one column

Tags: sql, if-statement, left-join, oracle-apex

I am pretty new in using SQL and trying to combine 2 tables within APEX ( interactive grid), based on the salary and rate the information to be taken from table X ( which i managed), but i need within the same SQL statement based on the information from column Type, to bring within column percentage if clauses to create the information.

and also within the same SQL statement to have the total which would be (rate*hours*percentage).

but it seems i just cant manager to combine so many codes into one correctly, i have tried different ways based on what i have found examples all over, but it seems it will just not work for some reason.

---

```
select 
Overtime.ID,
OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME,
OVERTIME."DATE",
OVERTIME.TYPE,
OVERTIME.HOURS,
EMPLOYEES.RATE,
EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
OVERTIME.PERCENTAGE (CASE
WHEN TYPE = "On Call " THEN "70%"
WHEN TYPE = "On Call PH" THEN "100%"
ELSE "150%"
END),
(Rate*hours*percentage) as total,
OVERTIME.CREATED,
OVERTIME.CREATED_BY
from OVERTIME 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES
ON OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
group by Employee_Number
```

---

```
select 
Overtime.ID,
OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME,
OVERTIME."DATE",
OVERTIME.TYPE,
OVERTIME.HOURS,
EMPLOYEES.RATE,
EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
OVERTIME.PERCENTAGE,
(Rate*hours*percentage) as total,
OVERTIME.CREATED,
OVERTIME.CREATED_BY
from OVERTIME 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES
ON OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
WHERE OVERTIME.TYPE LIKE 
 (CASE
   WHEN TYPE = "On Call " THEN "70%"
   WHEN TYPE = "On Call PH" THEN "100%"
   ELSE "150%"
 END);
group by Employee_number
```

The **table for Overtime** has the below:

```
ID Number primary Key
Employee_number vchar2
employee_full_name vchar2
date date
type vchar2
hours
salary number
rate number
percentage vachar2
total number
created timestamp
created_by vchar2
```

for the **Employees table**

```
ID number primary key
Employee_number vchar2
employee_full_name vchar2
salary number
rate number
```

i need to have the percentage information to reflect within the percentage column which i presume should be with if clause

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the total within the select statement using an SQL CASE statement.

Not sure that is the correct way to calculate the Total Pay - as you will want to Add the Basic Hourly rate to the % rate, but you can change that.

```
select 
    Overtime.ID,
    OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
    OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_FULL_NAME,
    OVERTIME."DATE",
    OVERTIME.TYPE,
    OVERTIME.HOURS,
    EMPLOYEES.RATE,
    EMPLOYEES.SALARY

    ,[Percentage] = CASE WHEN [Type] ='On Call ' THEN '70%'
                        WHEN [Type] = 'On Call PH' THEN '100%' 
                        ELSE  '150%'
                    END

    ,Total = CASE WHEN [Type] = 'On Call ' THEN (EMPLOYEES.RATE * OVERTIME.HOURS * 0.7)
                 WHEN [TYPE] = 'On Call PH THEN' THEN (EMPLOYEES.RATE * OVERTIME.HOURS)
                 ELSE  (EMPLOYEES.RATE * OVERTIME.HOURS * 1.5)
            END

    ,OVERTIME.CREATED
    ,OVERTIME.CREATED_BY

from OVERTIME  LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON OVERTIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
group by Employee_Number
```

Comment: Hello,Thank you very much! but it seems that the coding seems to have an issue saying in line 9 has a missing expression

Comment: @souzan88 please check now - fixed the syntax error

Comment: I'm having the same issue :(  "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 9, column 26: ORA-00936: missing expression</p>"

Comment: @souzan88 I can't help you further without sample data and schema of tables - this error maybe due to your query only grouping by Employee_Number in your question but you are selecting multiple columns which are not in the group by. I assumed you just required help on the Total Calculation.

Comment: I have added to the main question the tables, i hope that works? truly appreciate your help